# Values in input type not showing after a wait function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a simple function that does nothing:

```
function doNothing(){}
```

I also have a function that looks like this:

```
function getJson() {
    var JSONObject = {
        "name": "John Johnson",
        "street": "Oslo West 555",
        "age": 33,
        "phone": "5551234var stuff = <%= @var %>;567"
    };
    document.getElementById("name").value = JSONObject.name;
    setTimeout(doNothing(), 1000);
    document.getElementById("street").value = JSONObject.street;
```

So the `doNothing()` function is actually here only so I can put a parameter in the `setTimeout` function.

The point of the whole javascript code is that i want the first value to be shown immediatly and the second one after 1 second (1000miliseconds), but it never shows up.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setTimeout(doNothing(), 1000);` -- Wrong wrong wrong... It should be `setTimeout(doNothing, 1000);` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settimeout is not a sleep function, it will take a function and call it after 1000 milliseconds. Your other code will still execute right away.

Try:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = JSONObject.name;

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("street").value = JSONObject.street;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes much more sense. One thing only, why doesn't this work:
setTimeout(
    document.getElementById("street").value = JSONObject.street;
, 1000);

Comment: @Zippie - You have to put the scripts in a function, or else it would evaluate before putting inside `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Zippie when you pass a string to `setTimeout` (as is done in worthless tutorials), the code inside the string is ran in new context which doesn't know what `JSONObject.street` is

Comment: @Zippie: Have a look [at some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). `setTimeout` is not doing anything magical, it's a simple function. Whenever you put a statement somewhere, it will be evaluated. If I have `foo(a == 5, 'bar')` then `a` will be compared to `5` immediately and the result is passed to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delay the synchronous execution; JavaScript has no `sleep`-like function and please don't even think about emulating it using a loop and `Date` objects as that would hang the whole browser until the delay loop finished.

To solve you issue, simply put the code that should be delayed in the `setTimeout` callback function. Since it will be a closure you can easily access any variables that exist in the previous scope.

```
document.getElementById("name").value = JSONObject.name;
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("street").value = JSONObject.street;
}, 1000);
```

By the way, to execute the function `doNothing` after 1000ms, you would pass `doNothing` to `setTimeout` - when passing `doNothing()` you pass the return value of that function which is usually not what you want.